# How to connect and check all the files in a folder inside of a multiple servers using java

Tags: java

This is my first time in posting a question. I am trying to learn Java and tried to search in every site to find answers in my question. However, all that i found i am not able to apply nor understand.

My need your expertise in how can i do the following:

1. connect to multiple remote servers.(the address of the servers are listed in a text file).
2. check all the files inside a specific folder (D:\folder1\subfoler1)
3. send an email containing all the files listed inside the folder.

I am very much thank you in advance for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think step 1 and 2 depending on your 
circumstance. You willneed the appropriate library for your problem. Step 3, you can using javax.mail api of java for send email. goodluck :D